# Laravel Backpack redirect delete operation to list view

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to customize the delete operation such that whenever you delete an item, it goes back to the items list screen.
I have tried following; that I believed must work:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('delete');
    $this->crud->delete($id);      
    return redirect('/admin/students');
}
```

But it gives **405 methods not allowed** error. Does anyone have a better suggestion on how to achieve it?

Comment: Did you find any fix for this issue??

Answer (score 0):

You can just return 1 or true if success and 0 otherwise, it will be redirected its self (form the default code of delete button).